# Uncaught TypeError: fs_1.default.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am utilizing Parcel bundler in a project, but one of my biggest roadblocks is that I am making use of the `fs` module from the Node Standard Library and I get this error as a result:

`fs_1.default.readFileSync is not a function`

The above error is based on this logic:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

class Data {
  Address: string;
  General_Plan_Designation: string;
  Latitude: number;
  Longitude: number;

  static DELIMITER = ",";

  constructor(rawRow) {
    const data = rawRow.split(Data.DELIMITER);

    this.Address = data[0];
    this.General_Plan_Designation = data[1];
    this.Latitude = parseFloat(data[2]);
    this.Longitude = parseFloat(data[3]);
  }
}

const ROW_DELIMITER = "\r\n";

const rawData = fs.readFileSync("Cales_trim_down.csv", {
  encoding: "utf-8",
});

const data: Data[] = [];

for (const rawRow of rawData.split(ROW_DELIMITER)) {
  data.push(new Data(rawRow));
}

console.log(data);
```

I was told to do `import * as whateverFS from 'fs';` but that did not resolve the issue. I was told to go into the `tsconfig.json` file and ensure esModule something or other is set to `true` but Parcel does not have one, not one I can reconfigure at least.

How do I get Node Standard Library modules to work with Parcel?

Comment: To resolve `fs_1.default.readFileSync is not a function`, set `esModuleInterop` to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`, or use import-all notation, eg `import * from 'fs'`. It sounds like you might be running into path resolution issues, though - when you say `fs.readFileSync('foo.txt')`, you're asking for a file named `foo.txt` _in the directory where you ran `node`_. Generally it's best to use absolute paths, to make sure you're not reliant on the node process's working directory.

Comment: If the file you want to read is located in the same directory as the `.js`/`.ts` file that's importing it, you can do `fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'foo.txt'))` (`__dirname` contains the absolute path of the current file).

Comment: @superhawk610, I tried your suggestions, but I continue to get the same error. What about some how implementing `this.filename`? I have not been successful myself. I mean I would have to place, `const data = fs.readFileSync("Data-Table 1.csv", {
  encoding: "utf-8",
});` inside the `Address` class and then that just creates more problems down the line especially when it gets down here, `for (const rawRow of data.split(ROW_DELIMITER)) {
  rawAddress.push(new Address(rawRow));
}`.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @superhawk610, I was getting the same error. I tried another refactor where I am now getting a console log, just not the console log I was looking for. It looks like I probably should delete this OP and ask a new one now.

Comment: @superhawk610, I know what the issue is, its Parcel, but I need to use the parcel-bundler. Any idea how to get Parcel bundler to work nicely with Node Standard Library modules?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1736

Comment: @Ankit, this right here solved it for me from your link: `import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
const raw = readFileSync(__dirname + '/raw.tsx', 'utf-8');`. Feel free to post it as the answer to this OP and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when using TypeScript with Node Standard Library modules and running a local server with Parcel, you can't just install Parcel globally and run it like `parcel index.html` as I was doing.

In this case you have to create a `package.json` file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build ./src/index.ts --target node",
    "start": "parcel index.html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

That's part A of the solution, part B is instead of using `fs.readFileSync()` you have to just import `readFileSync()` like so:

```
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
```

and apply it like so:

```
export const rawData = readFileSync("src/Cales_trim_down.csv", {
  encoding: "utf-8",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Parcel 2, the recommend way to **read a file as literal, plain text** is using the [`bundle-text:` scheme](https://parceljs.org/features/bundle-inlining/#inlining-a-bundle-as-text).

Example:

```js
import text from 'bundle-text:./myFile';
console.log(text);
```